# Keep just a certain amount of duplicate value in an array in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, filtering

I have an array like this:

```
array
(
  [0] => array(
    'title' => 'pizza',
    'store_id' => 65
  ),
  [1] => array(
    'title' => 'hamburger',
    'store_id' => 65
  ),
  [2] => array(
    'title' => 'sandwich',
    'store_id' => 65
  ),
  [3] => array(
    'title' => 'soda',
    'store_id' => 65
  ),
  [4] => array(
    'title' => 'salad',
    'store_id' => 50
  ),
 )
)
```

I need to filter this to get only 3 items of each store. It can be the first 3 occurrences.

Any ideas to solve this?

Obs: There's a lot more items and columns in each array.

Comment: Create an object where you keep a counter of items for each store. When the counter reaches 3, stop adding the duplicates to the result array.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, I found a solution based on it and will post it here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just found a way to this based on @Barmar's tip for adding a counter:

```
function limit_items($items_array, $counter = 3) {
    $filtered = array();
    $stores_added = array();

    foreach($items_array as $item) {
                    
        $occurrences = array_filter($stores_added, function($store) use($item) {
            return $store == $item['store']['name'];
        });
                    
        if(count($occurrences) < $counter) {
            array_push($stores_added, $item['store']['name']);
            array_push($filtered, $item);
        }
    }

    return $filtered;
}

$stores_array = limit_items_by_store($stores_array, 3);
```

First I set 2 variables as arrays. One for the whole filtered array and the other one for stores added.

After I loop through all items and then set a `$occurrences` filter for store name, and then I compare the occurrences length with the counter `3`. While it doesn't reaches it, push the store name to `$stores_added` array and push current item to `$filtered` array.

Maybe there will be a better way to do this but works like a charm for me.